Filtering JSON Field in PostgreSQL with SQLAlchemy
I'm working with a PostgreSQL database using SQLAlchemy in fastAPI, and I need to filter results based on a value in a JSON array column. However, I'm encountering an issue where the filter does not work as expected.
I have a table with a column services that is of type JSON. Here is a simplified version of my SQLAlchemy model :
class Element(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    services = Column(JSON, nullable=True)

And here is my query :
query = db.query(Element)

if filters:
    if 'services' in filters:
        query = query.filter(Element.services.contains([filters['services']]))

When I try to filter by the services column, I get the following error:
FROM elements WHERE (elements.services LIKE '%%' || %(services_1)s || '%%')) AS anon_1] [parameters: {'services_1': '["Test"]'}] (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/f405) INFO:     172.18.0.1:43390 - "GET /elements/?skip=0&limit=10&services=Test HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
How can I correctly filter records based on a value in a JSON array column using SQLAlchemy and PostgreSQL?
EDIT
Here is an example of the data stored in the services column:
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "services": ["service1", "service2", "Test"]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "services": ["service3", "service4"]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "services": ["service2", "service5", "Test"]
  }
]

For the filter services="Test", I expect the query to return:
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "services": ["service1", "service2", "Test"]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "services": ["service2", "service5", "Test"]
  }
]


I could resolve my issue with two ways :

Define services as JSONB
services = Column(JSONB, nullable=True)

if 'services' in filters:
    query = query.filter(professional_model.Professional.services.op('@>')(cast(func.to_jsonb([filters['services']]), JSONB)))


Define services as ARRAY
services = Column(ARRAY(String), nullable=True)

if 'services' in filters:
    query = query.filter(professional_model.Professional.services.any(filters['services']))

